# Is a T test the right thing to do?

Tags: t-test

I have performed a survey which contains 2 logical sets of people (A and B). 
In my data set there were roughly twice as many respondents in set A as there were in set B.
The survey asks "Do you have a qualification in your field". So my answers are all Yes or No.

I want to know if the difference between the answers is statistically significant.

Does a 2 sample t-test work here?

Comment: Alexis' answer addresses the important issues well, but there's some additional points you may find useful:1.  the answers Yes and No are clearly different; you mean to compare the proportions of those answers across your groups, not the answers themselves. (no doubt this objection seems trivial, but I have seen situations barely any more complicated than this lead to ongoing confusion when the intent was not clearly expressed; it's better - not least for your own understanding - to be clear that you're comparing proportions) 2. Given that you code the answers into two distinct numbers, ...ctd

Comment: ctd... the distributional assumption for the t-test - that the population of responses are normally distributed - won't apply  (though this won't be much of an issue if the sample isn't too small)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a *t* test. But you might consider a *z* test instead:

$H_{0}: p_{A} - p_{B} = 0; H_{A}: p_{A} - p_{B} \ne 0$

$z = \frac{p_{A}-p_{B}}{\sigma_{p_{A}-p_{B}}}$, where

$\sigma_{p_{A}-p_{B}} = \sqrt{\hat{p}\left(1-\hat{p}\right)\left[\frac{1}{n_{A}} + \frac{1}{n_{B}}\right]}$, and where

$\hat{p}$ is the proportion from all your data, regardless of which group the data came from. ($n_{A}$ and $n_{B}$ are the sample sizes of each group.)

The *p*-value from this test is $p = P(|Z| \ge z)$ (where $Z$ is the standard normal distribution).

That will work pretty well if you have a large sample enough sample size in both $A$ and $B$. But a continuity correction for $z$ can help:

$z = \frac{|p_{A}-p_{B}| - \frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{1}{n_{A}} + \frac{1}{n_{B}}\right]}{\sigma_{p_{A}-p_{B}}}$.

Using this continuity correction means you will need to interpret the direction of a significant difference (i.e. which group's proportion is larger) by comparing $p_{A}$ and $p_{B}$, as the sign of the test is positive.

Finally, you have yet another option, which is to use a $\chi^{2}$ contingency table test of the same null hypothesis above. Let me know if you want the details on that.

Comment: Unfortunately my data set is very small - I only received 20 responses in total.

So, if my data looks like this (for example):

Group A:
Yes
No 
Yes
No
No
No

Group B:
Yes
No 
Yes
No
No
No
Yes
Yes

How do I calculate the 2 sample t-test value? Do I set Yes = 1, No =1 and then calculate the mean value for each group?

Would you recomend the chi squared approach?

Comment: I would recommend either the *z* test with the continuity correction above, or, if your prefer $\chi^{2}$ tests a $\chi^{2}$ test with a continuity correction. Neither one will be more powerful for your situation.

Comment: Thanks - are you suggesting the z or chi test due to the data set size?

Comment: What I would ***really*** recommend doing, though is (i) deciding how different the two proportions need to be for you to care (i.e. different by 0.1 is important, but different by 0.05 is too small to care about), (ii) also conducting a [test for equivalence](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/tost/info) using your value from (i), and (iii) performing a relevance test by combining your the test for difference I outlined in my answer with your test for equivalence, thereby avoiding confirmation bias, and situating power and effect size directly in your conclusions.

Comment: Ruth I am not suggesting either one; they are equally powerful, and will produce identical test results. It's really a matter of preference. If you find my answer useful I hope you will consider up-voting it and/or accepting it as an answer.

Comment: Ok - So the 2 tailed p value comes out at 0.0528 which from what you've said above seems like to small to care about :) I'll take a look at a test for equivilance etc.

I used this tool https://www.graphpad.com/quickcalcs/ttest2/ and enter for group 1:
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0 and for group 2: 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1

Thanks!

Comment: Ruth there is a confusion, sorry: the *p*-value for a test is different than the difference in proportions that is too small to care about. The former is how likely your test statistic is if the null hypothesis is true, the latter is your preference (i.e. a difference between A and B big enough to care about). Different things.